# Error in plotting a Point Chart programmatically using MS Chart

Tags: .net, mschart

I have to plot an XY chart using MS-Chart feature.The requirement is to plot five different points (each having a different X and Y coordinate and a differemt Marker Style).Thus,in this case both X and Y points need to be plotted.

Please help me in doing it.I tried using a 'Point' Chart for this but somehow it doesnt work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this...

```
        //// initialize an array of doubles for Y values
        double[] yval = { 5, 6, 4, 6, 3 };
        // initialize an array of strings for X values
        double[] xval = { 1, 4, 6, 8, 9 };
        // bind the arrays to the X and Y values of data points in the "ByArray" series
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(xval, yval);
        chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[0].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Square;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[1].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Cross; 
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[2].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Triangle; 
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[3].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[4].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Star4;
```